# Using RequireJS and AMD to distribute a project that contains internal dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have an open-source JavaScript form-validation library that I've created. Recently a contributor helpfully modified my library to support AMD. In the past month or two, I have been refactoring my library to enhance maintainability, modularity, and readability. Essentially I have extracted pieces of logic into self-contained modules. However, these modules all reside inside the main module.

After looking at how AMD does things, I feel that it would be beneficial if I am able to split these internal modules into their own separate files. I come from a Java background, and from that perspective, these individual modules seem like classes to me and I'd like to separate them out. This will also help me manage my dependencies better and also enforce proper modularity. I think in the long run, this will make the code much better.

I know that RequireJS has an "optimize" feature whereby it will combine all dependencies into a single file and minimize it.

My question is this: will this minified file also be AMD compatible? That is, will the file expose itself as an AMD module? The dependencies that the project itself has are all internal and I don't want to expose them separately. However, I would still like developers to be able to import my library as a self-contained module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will this minified file also be AMD compatible? That is, will the file
>   expose itself as an AMD module?

Require.js doesn't necessary generate a AMD compatible module. You have to make your library AMD compatible. It should happen in your `main` file. You can learn it from [lowdash](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L5425) how to do it. They created their library compatible with Node and Require.js. They basically looking for global variables to detect Node and Require.

```
/** Detect free variable `exports` */
  var freeExports = typeof exports == 'object' && exports;

  /** Detect free variable `module` */
  var freeModule = typeof module == 'object' && module && module.exports == freeExports && module;

  /** Detect free variable `global` and use it as `window` */
  var freeGlobal = typeof global == 'object' && global;
  if (freeGlobal.global === freeGlobal) {
    window = freeGlobal;
  }
```

At the end:

```
    // if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd == 'object' && define.amd) {
    // Expose Lo-Dash to the global object even when an AMD loader is present in
    // case Lo-Dash was injected by a third-party script and not intended to be
    // loaded as a module. The global assignment can be reverted in the Lo-Dash
    // module via its `noConflict()` method.
    window._ = _;

    // define as an anonymous module so, through path mapping, it can be
    // referenced as the "underscore" module
    define(function() {
      return _;
    });
  }
  // check for `exports` after `define` in case a build optimizer adds an `exports` object
  else if (freeExports && !freeExports.nodeType) {
    // in Node.js or RingoJS v0.8.0+
    if (freeModule) {
      (freeModule.exports = _)._ = _;
    }
    // in Narwhal or RingoJS v0.7.0-
    else {
      freeExports._ = _;
    }
  }
  else {
    // in a browser or Rhino
    window._ = _;
  }
```

Comment: [Here's](https://raw.github.com/vivin/regula/master/src/regula.js) the source to my library. I believe it's currently AMD compatible. I intend to split the inner modules into separate files that are also themselves, AMD compatible. When I optimize with RequireJS, will the resulting minified file (which contains all the other modules) also be AMD compatible?

Comment: If you explicitly `define` it, yes. It would be AMD compatible.